# android studio wifi debugging

Tags: android, android-studio, android-wifi

When I am trying to pair my realme 9 4g using wifi debugging i am not able do it.
When click on the pair with qr code. the camera is not recognizing the QR code and also when using pairing code, my laptop is not showing the name of my device.

Both of my devices are connected to same wifi.

How can i resolve it ?

Comment: Have you enabled wifi-debugging? Also have you tried to pair from terminal using `adb pair your_device_ip:port`?

Comment: I have enabled wifi debugging. After running this command its giving me.                                                                       " adb : The term 'adb' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, 
or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify 
that the path is correct and try again. "

Comment: Sorry I thought you already had adb, you can get it [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools) just open the folder where adb.exe is located (or set it as environment variable) and run the command